# Multiple w3Schools Lightboxes (Modal Boxes) on same page: modal boxes only showing first modal's content

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, lightbox

I'm still new to HTML/CSS and I have no idea about Javascript. I need three lightboxes of images on a page with button tabs, where each button reveals a page with a lightbox on it. I originally used W3Schools lightbox code (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp) but I have altered it here and there.

All of the images in the tabs look fine, but when you click on them they pop up with the first lightbox/modal's content. I also noticed that my previous/next buttons will now only go through the content once and then go blank for a few clicks. That's not the problem I'm most concerned with fixing, but perhaps it will give someone insight to what's wrong.

I've tried many possible solutions, including changing class names and id names (because I learned that you shouldn't have multiple divs with same id name), but it didn't work for me, so I brought the code back to how I began with it. I even changed the slide numbers that the modal box picks up so that the second modal box's slides were numbered 4,5,6 instead of 1,2,3, but still no luck. Any ideas?

Thanks!

HTML, CSS, & JAVASCRIPT below. Please note that the javascript is in the HTML file because that's how I have it in my document, so I thought I'd keep everything consistent. Also looks like there are many errors in the code- sorry I don't know how to fix them :/

```css
html
{
    width:500px;
    margin:auto;
}

/* BUTTON COLORS */
.light-blue
    {background-color: #4e9abe;}
.pea-green
    {background-color: #a39a4b;}
.teal
    {background-color: #298e86;}



/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
  line-height:1.3;
}



/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #999900;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Hide the slides by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: #4e7977;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


.next a, .prev a
{
    text-decoration: none;
}


.modal-images
{max-height:75vh;
    max-width:auto;
    border-radius:5%;
    border:2px dotted;
    display: inline;
    }

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
   
    display: inline-block;
    width:133px;
    height:133px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin:4px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:#f5f5f5;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border:none;
}


.topright:hover {color: red;}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background: #746572;}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
    border: 3px #505050 dashed;
    padding:5px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    outline:none;
}
/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    width:100%;
}


/* Style the close button */
.topright {
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 28px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


    
    
<script>
    // Open the Modal
    function openModal() 
    {document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";}
    // Close the Modal
    function closeModal()
    {document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";}
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);
    // Next/previous controls
    function plusSlides(n)
    {showSlides(slideIndex += n);}
    // Thumbnail image controls
    function currentSlide(n) 
    {showSlides(slideIndex = n);}
    function showSlides(n)
    {var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++)
    {slides[i].style.display = "none";}
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++)
    {dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");}
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;}
</script>


<!--JAVASCRIPT FOR KEYBOARD NAVIGATION (PREV, NEXT, AND ESCAPE BUTTONS)-->
<script>
    document.onkeydown = function (e) 
    {e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {document.querySelector('.prev').click();}
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {document.querySelector('.close').click();}    
    else if (e.keyCode == 39) {document.querySelector('.next').click();}};
</script>



<div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks pea-green" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab1')">Tab 1</button>
  
    <button class="tablinks light-blue" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab2')">Tab 2</button>
  
    <button class="tablinks teal" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab3')">Tab 3 </button>
</div>


<div id="tab1" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times;</span>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image1" class="modal-images" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image2" class="modal-images" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image3" class="modal-images" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)">
</div>  
    
    <!--CLICKED-ON IMAGES IN MODAL BOX-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
<div class="modal-content">
    
    <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image1" class="modal-images" onclick="currentSlide(2)">
    <br>Modal Box Image 1, Modal 1
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image2" class="modal-images" onclick="currentSlide(3)">
    <br>Modal Box Image 2, Modal 1
    </div> 
    <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image3" class="modal-images" onclick="currentSlide(1)">
    <br>Modal Box Image 3, Modal 1
    </div>
    

    
    
     <!-- NEXT/PREVIOUS CONTROLS -->
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>   
   
    
    
       
    
    
   
</div>
  

      
<div id="tab2" class="tabcontent">
   <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times;</span>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image4" class="modal-images" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image5" class="modal-images" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image6" class="modal-images" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)">
</div>  
    
    <!--CLICKED-ON IMAGES IN MODAL BOX-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
<div class="modal-content">
    
    <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image4" class="modal-images" onclick="currentSlide(2)">
    <br>Modal Box Image 4, Modal 2
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image5" class="modal-images" onclick="currentSlide(3)">
    <br>Modal Box Image 5, Modal 2
    </div> 
    <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image6" class="modal-images" onclick="currentSlide(1)">
    <br>Modal Box Image 6, Modal 2
    </div>
    

    
    
     <!-- NEXT/PREVIOUS CONTROLS -->
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>


</div>
</div>  

<div id="tab3" class="tabcontent">
    <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times;</span>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image7" class="modal-images" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image8" class="modal-images" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image9" class="modal-images" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)">
</div>  
    
    <!--CLICKED-ON IMAGES IN MODAL BOX-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
<div class="modal-content">
    
    <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image7" class="modal-images" onclick="currentSlide(2)">
    <br>Modal Box Image 7, Modal 3
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image8" class="modal-images" onclick="currentSlide(3)">
    <br>Modal Box Image 8, Modal 3
    </div> 
    <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image9" class="modal-images" onclick="currentSlide(1)">
    <br>Modal Box Image 9, Modal 3
    </div>
    
    
    <!-- NEXT/PREVIOUS CONTROLS -->
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
    
  
    
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really only want one element with the `#myModal` id, so basically, I just deleted a bunch of redundant code and moved your `.tabcontent` markup outside the modal markup. Then I changed the currentSlide() function parameters to their index respective of the total number of images. This way, when you click on image5, for example, the modal actually opens to image5. See http://jsfiddle.net/qryu0dmL/19/

```
<script>
    // Open the Modal
    function openModal() 
    {document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";}
    // Close the Modal
    function closeModal()
    {document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";}
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);
    // Next/previous controls
    function plusSlides(n)
    {showSlides(slideIndex += n);}
    // Thumbnail image controls
    function currentSlide(n) 
    {showSlides(slideIndex = n);}
    function showSlides(n)
    {var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++)
    {slides[i].style.display = "none";}
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++)
    {dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");}
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;}
</script>


<!--JAVASCRIPT FOR KEYBOARD NAVIGATION (PREV, NEXT, AND ESCAPE BUTTONS)-->
<script>
    document.onkeydown = function (e) 
    {e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {document.querySelector('.prev').click();}
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {document.querySelector('.close').click();}    
    else if (e.keyCode == 39) {document.querySelector('.next').click();}};
</script>



<div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks pea-green" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab1')">Tab 1</button>

    <button class="tablinks light-blue" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab2')">Tab 2</button>

    <button class="tablinks teal" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab3')">Tab 3 </button>
</div>


<div id="tab1" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times;</span>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image1" class="modal-images" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image2" class="modal-images" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image3" class="modal-images" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)">
</div>  
<div id="tab2" class="tabcontent">
   <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times;</span>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image4" class="modal-images" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image5" class="modal-images" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(5)">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image6" class="modal-images" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(6)">
</div>  
<div id="tab3" class="tabcontent">
    <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times;</span>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image7" class="modal-images" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(7)">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image8" class="modal-images" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(8)">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image9" class="modal-images" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(9)">
</div>  


    <!--CLICKED-ON IMAGES IN MODAL BOX-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
<div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image1" class="modal-images" onclick="currentSlide(2)">
    <br>Modal Box Image 1, Modal 1
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image2" class="modal-images" onclick="currentSlide(3)">
    <br>Modal Box Image 2, Modal 1
    </div> 
    <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image3" class="modal-images" onclick="currentSlide(1)">
    <br>Modal Box Image 3, Modal 1
    </div>



    <!--CLICKED-ON IMAGES IN MODAL BOX-->


    <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image4" class="modal-images" onclick="currentSlide(2)">
    <br>Modal Box Image 4, Modal 2
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image5" class="modal-images" onclick="currentSlide(3)">
    <br>Modal Box Image 5, Modal 2
    </div> 
    <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image6" class="modal-images" onclick="currentSlide(1)">
    <br>Modal Box Image 6, Modal 2
    </div>



    <!--CLICKED-ON IMAGES IN MODAL BOX-->


    <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image7" class="modal-images" onclick="currentSlide(2)">
    <br>Modal Box Image 7, Modal 3
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image8" class="modal-images" onclick="currentSlide(3)">
    <br>Modal Box Image 8, Modal 3
    </div> 
    <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image9" class="modal-images" onclick="currentSlide(1)">
    <br>Modal Box Image 9, Modal 3
    </div>

         <!-- NEXT/PREVIOUS CONTROLS -->
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks- this definitely allows each modal box to pull up the content from the image that's clicked on, but when I use the previous/next buttons it scrolls through the content from the other modal boxes. So lightbox number one's modal images on click-through show me images 1, 2, 3 (as wanted) but then keep going on to 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.  Same with the 2nd and 3rd lightbox, start on the right image but then scroll through the images in all the other modal boxes, too.  Any ideas on why that could be? :o

Comment: I thought that was the desired behavior. Do you only want the modal to cycle through each group of 3?

Comment: Yes. So, basically, I'm making a graphic design portfolio page. One tab will be "posters" one will be "logos" and one will be "illustration", so when you click on the first tab I want a lightbox with just poster images, second tab being just logos, etc. Is this possible? I'm sorry I should've been clearer. Thank you so much for your help! It's very appreciated.

Comment: Before, the first modal box was fine- when you click an image, it pulled up the first modal box's image. The problem was that when you clicked on images from the second and third modal box, they also pulled up the first modal box's images, not the second and third like I wanted them too.

Comment: It's definitely possible, but it seems pretty tricky without totally refactoring the code. I'd personally recommend implementing a jQuery slider plugin like this one unless there's some reason you can't use it: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Yeah, a slider won't really work as then a visitor would have to view the portfolio images one at a time. I'd rather them see thumbnails on the page of everything, but be able to click on any of them for an enlarged image. Just need three different lightbox galleries in three different tabs on the same page. :/ I feel like it's so close to working! I just need it to only rotate through each lightbox individually, and stop going through the other lightboxes with prev/next.

Comment: Alright man. Here you go. This is really not good code, but it seems like it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/qryu0dmL/154/

Comment: You just made my whole life. THANK YOU SO MUCH! Seriously, you are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Your script is not working because you have placed it ahead of the DOM elements it is trying to access. HTML documents are parsed from top to bottom so the script would be executed before the elements are created. Thus, you need to place the script after the DOM elements.

Also, your have 9 elements with a class of `mySlides` so your `showSlide` function will not work. I have changed your logic to check if the number of the slide to be shown is more than 3 (set it to 1) or less than 1 (set it to 3).

```css
html
{
    width:500px;
    margin:auto;
}

/* BUTTON COLORS */
.light-blue
    {background-color: #4e9abe;}
.pea-green
    {background-color: #a39a4b;}
.teal
    {background-color: #298e86;}



/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
  line-height:1.3;
}



/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #999900;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Hide the slides by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: #4e7977;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


.next a, .prev a
{
    text-decoration: none;
}


.modal-images
{max-height:75vh;
    max-width:auto;
    border-radius:5%;
    border:2px dotted;
    display: inline;
    }

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
   
    display: inline-block;
    width:133px;
    height:133px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin:4px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:#f5f5f5;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border:none;
}


.topright:hover {color: red;}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background: #746572;}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
    border: 3px #505050 dashed;
    padding:5px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    outline:none;
}
/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    width:100%;
}


/* Style the close button */
.topright {
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 28px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  



<!--JAVASCRIPT FOR KEYBOARD NAVIGATION (PREV, NEXT, AND ESCAPE BUTTONS)-->
<script>
    document.onkeydown = function (e) 
    {var e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.querySelectorAll('.prev')[0].click();}
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.querySelectorAll('.close')[0].click();}    
    else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.querySelectorAll('.next')[0].click();}};
</script>



<div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks pea-green" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab1')">Tab 1</button>
  
    <button class="tablinks light-blue" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab2')">Tab 2</button>
  
    <button class="tablinks teal" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab3')">Tab 3 </button>
</div>


<div id="tab1" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times;</span>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image1" class="modal-images" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image2" class="modal-images" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image3" class="modal-images" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)">
</div>  
    
    <!--CLICKED-ON IMAGES IN MODAL BOX-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
<div class="modal-content">
    
    <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image1" class="modal-images" onclick="currentSlide(2)">
    <br>Modal Box Image 1, Modal 1
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image2" class="modal-images" onclick="currentSlide(3)">
    <br>Modal Box Image 2, Modal 1
    </div> 
    <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image3" class="modal-images" onclick="currentSlide(1)">
    <br>Modal Box Image 3, Modal 1
    </div>
    

    
    
     <!-- NEXT/PREVIOUS CONTROLS -->
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>   
   
    
    
       
    
    
   
</div>
  

      
<div id="tab2" class="tabcontent">
   <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times;</span>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image4" class="modal-images" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image5" class="modal-images" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image6" class="modal-images" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)">
</div>  
    
    <!--CLICKED-ON IMAGES IN MODAL BOX-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
<div class="modal-content">
    
    <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image4" class="modal-images" onclick="currentSlide(2)">
    <br>Modal Box Image 4, Modal 2
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image5" class="modal-images" onclick="currentSlide(3)">
    <br>Modal Box Image 5, Modal 2
    </div> 
    <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image6" class="modal-images" onclick="currentSlide(1)">
    <br>Modal Box Image 6, Modal 2
    </div>
    

    
    
     <!-- NEXT/PREVIOUS CONTROLS -->
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>


</div>
</div>  

<div id="tab3" class="tabcontent">
    <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times;</span>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image7" class="modal-images" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image8" class="modal-images" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image9" class="modal-images" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)">
</div>  
    
    <!--CLICKED-ON IMAGES IN MODAL BOX-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
<div class="modal-content">
    
    <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image7" class="modal-images" onclick="currentSlide(2)">
    <br>Modal Box Image 7, Modal 3
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image8" class="modal-images" onclick="currentSlide(3)">
    <br>Modal Box Image 8, Modal 3
    </div> 
    <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image9" class="modal-images" onclick="currentSlide(1)">
    <br>Modal Box Image 9, Modal 3
    </div>
    
    
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
</div>
<script>
    // Open the Modal
    function openModal() 
    {document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";}
    // Close the Modal
    function closeModal()
    {document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";}
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);
    // Next/previous controls
    function plusSlides(n)
    {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }
    // Thumbnail image controls
    function currentSlide(n) 
    {showSlides(slideIndex = n);}
    function showSlides(n)
    {var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    //var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    if (n > 3) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = 3}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++)
    {slides[i].style.display = "none";}
    //for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++)
    //{dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");}
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    //dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    //captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
    }
</script>
<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
    
  
    
</html>
```

Comment: This code still acts the same as my original post. When i click on the 2nd or 3rd tab, and click on an image, the modal box that pops up is still the one for the first modal box. When I click on image 7 on tab 3, image 1 pops up in the modal box. Is there something I can do to fix this?